# How can I write a link text containing a square bracket in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, rocket.chat

I'm using Rocket.Chat and trying to link using link text like this:

```
[link-text]
```

However, when I try

```
[[link-text]](http://example.com/)
```

...it doesn't work, and when I try

```
[\[link-text\]](http://example.com/)
```

...it is recognized as KaTeX.

How can I write a link containing a square bracket in Rocket.Chat?

Comment: For what it's worth: escaping [works in commonmark](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%5B%5C%5Blink-text%5C%5D%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F))

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in the Markdown implementation you are using. You should report it to the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **fullwidth square brackets** ([U+FF3B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3b/index.htm), [U+FF3D](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3d/index.htm)) instead:

```
[［link-text］](http://example.com/)
```

**Result:**

[image: result of formatting]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[[link-text](http://example.com/)]
```

Which renders as: [[link-text](http://example.com/)].

Only downside is that this solution does not include the [] "inside" the link.